# How to find sum of first three digits

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm new in Java and I try to find the sum of first three digits in `int` number.
I have a number `123456` I want to find the sum of first three digits `123` and then find sum of last three digits `456` and then compare it. I can't understand how to do this. I code next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number:");
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    int length = (int) Math.ceil(Math.log10(number));

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println(length);
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

I think that I shoud to use for loop, but I'm not sure. I know how to count the length of a number. But how to how to find the sum of the first three numbers and last three?

Comment: You'd find it easier if you used `scanner.next()` to get the number as a `String`. Then you can simply use `length()` and `substring()`.

Comment: What if the number has less then 6 digits?

Comment: @Tunaki just for a beginner I don't think they need to be worrying about cleaning inputs - they just want to see the code's logic work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way of doing it, making the assumption that your integer has an even number of digits...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Makes the assumption that the input integer contains an even number of digits.
        int x = 123456;
        String s = Integer.toString(x);
        int[] count = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            int digit = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 1));
            int countIndex = (int)Math.floor(i * 2 / s.length());
            count[countIndex] += digit;
        }

        int half = s.length() / 2;
        System.out.println("First Sum of " + s.substring(0, half) + ": " + count[0]);
        System.out.println("Second Sum of " + s.substring(half) + ": " + count[1]);
    }
}
```

**Alternate Method**

Here's another way of doing it without using the arrays above, and actually simplified the logic by abstracting the sum to a method.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Makes the assumption that the input integer contains an even number of digits.
        int x = 123456;
        String s = Integer.toString(x);
        int half = s.length() / 2;
        String firstHalf = s.substring(0, half);
        String secondHalf = s.substring(half);
        System.out.println(firstHalf);
        System.out.println(secondHalf);
        int sum1 = sumString(firstHalf);
        int sum2 = sumString(secondHalf);
        System.out.println("Sum 1: " + sum1);
        System.out.println("Sum 2: " + sum2);
    }

    private static int sumString(String s) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 1));
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works! As I understand you use arrays. I have not studied the arrays yet.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative way of doing it, without any arrays (although that was just to make it easy to store the sums) and abstracting the sum out to a new method.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your length is constant (6):

```
String first = (""+number).substring(0, 3);
String second = (""+number).substring(3, 6);
int firstSum = 0;
int secondSum = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < first.length; x++)
    firstSum += Integer.parseInt(first.charAt(x)+"");
for (int x = 0; x < second.length; x++)
    secondSum += Integer.parseInt(second.charAt(x)+"");
System.out.println("Sum of first 3: " + firstSum);
System.out.println("Sum of second 3: " + secondSum);
```

Read the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)- it has a lot of useful methods. For small programs like this, it's usually pretty easy to convert to String, use String methods, then parse back to int.

EDIT: Andy Turner and Jeremy Kato informed me about `Character.getNumericValue()`. Thus, the statement:

```
firstSum += Integer.parseInt(first.charAt(x)+"");
```

Could be changed to:

```
firstSum += Character.getNumericValue(first.charAt(x));
```

Likewise for `secondSum`.

Comment: You can do the extraction of digit values without the string creation using `Character.getNumericValue(char)`.

Answer (score 1):

First, probably should correct your spelling of length - though maybe not, because you don't really need that variable to do this.

What your code should do to make this easier for you is to *not* convert the input into an `int` immediately. You'll first want to split the input string into two pieces, then take the two numbers and sum them up with a loop.

Here's my idea of what I'd do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number:");
    String input = scanner.nextLine();

    String firstHalf = input.substring(0, 3); // note that depending on how 
                // many digits you want to change, these numbers must change as well.
    String secondHalf = input.substring(3); 

    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;


    // don't forget: start at 0, not 1!
    for(int i = 0; i<=3; i++){

        sum1 += Character.getNumericValue(firstHalf.charAt(i));     
        sum2 += Character.getNumericValue(secondHalf.charAt(i));
        // this call to the Character class converts a character to an int. 

    }

    System.out.println(sum1);
    System.out.println(sum2);

}
```

Just note that this code is made to work with your input being 6 characters, and it assumes they're going to be numbers. It'll crash if you enter too few characters in or if you put letters in, but you can always worry about that later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution which doesn't use Strings or arrays:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int num=123456;
    int second = 0;
    int first = 0;      

    second = addLastThree(num);
    num /= 1000;
    first = addLastThree(num);

    System.out.println("first -- > " + first);
    System.out.println("second -- > " + second);


}

static int addLastThree(int num){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i =0; i<3; i++){
        sum += (num/Math.pow(10,i)) % 10;
    }   
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code and every line was explained in comments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number:");
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    int n=number; //duplicating the value for the reference.
int l = (int) Math.log10(number) + 1; //Length of the number
int half = l/2; //to find half length of the number to sum first and last digits seperately.
int last_Sum = 0; //to store sum of last digits
int first_Sum = 0; //to store sum of first digits
for(int i=0; i<half && number>0; i++){ //to sum last digits
    last_Sum = last_Sum + number%10;
    number = number/10;
}for(int i=0; i<half && number>0; i++){ //to sum first digits
    first_Sum = first_Sum + number%10;
    number = number/10;
}
System.out.println("Length of the number "+l);
System.out.println("Number is "+n);
System.out.println("Sum of last digits "+last_Sum);
System.out.println("Sum of first digits "+first_Sum);}}
```